# How to resize the HTML document size according to the browser's window size?

Tags: javascript

My situation: I am loading a huge image into my web app, the browser is adapting the size of the image. Then I am re-sizing the image to fit the browser's window size, but i can still scroll down and there is a lot of empty space because the document did not adapt its size to the new re-sized image.

I'm trying to do something like this but it won't work:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();  // returns width of browser viewport
var windowHeight =$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
var documentWidth = $(document).width(); // returns height of HTML document
var documentHeight = $(document).height(); // returns width of HTML document

documentWidth.resizeTo(windowWidth);
documentHeight.resizeTo(windowHeight);
```

Comment: This is automatic. Unless you've fixed it using CSS you can leave it alone.

Comment: well technically the html document will always be the same as the browser size....

Comment: my situation is difficult to explain but I do need to rechange the document size according to the window size after all my scripts have loaded or else I will have a big scroller and 60% of my page will be empty.

Comment: Untrue, @HuangChen on mobile devices the keyboard can mess things up

Comment: why not give the body percents?

Comment: perhaps I am not wording my question correctly. This is more or less whats happening. I am loading a huge image into my web app, the browser is adapting the size of the image. Then I am re-sizing the image to fit the browser's window size, but i can still scroll down and there is a lot of empty space because the document did not adapt its size to the new resized image

Answer (score 0):

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();  // returns width of browser viewport
var windowHeight =$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
var documentWidth = $(document).width(windowWidth); // sets height of HTML document
var documentHeight = $(document).height(windowHeight); // sets width of HTML document
```

You need to set the document's size to the window's.

`resizeTo()` also isn't a property of numbers, and it doesn't do what you think it does.